# Apache on Windows not releasing port 80 on service stop, and will not restart

Tags: apache, pid

When I try to restart Apache it throws the following error:

```
============================================
Apache 2 is starting ...
(OS 10048)Normalerweise darf jede Socketadresse (Protokoll, Netzwerkadresse oder Anschluss) nur jeweils einmal verwendet werden.
: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
=============================================
```

I used netstat, and found that the PID holding port 80 was the same PID that Apache was previously using.  This PID does not show up in task manager, and it is not found when taskkill is attempted on it.

It seems that Apache is somehow holding onto the port on exit.  The only way I can restart the Apache service is by changing the Listen port each time, or by restarting the server itself.

Has anyone come across this before, and if so, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Should probably be on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Is there anything in the logs from shutdown? There should be something to the effect of "...Child Process exited succesfully".  Also, you can use the `taskkill` command to terminate the process. `taskkill /F /PID 12345` will forcefully terminate the process with PID 12345

Comment: The shutdown logs said exactly that.  Child Process exited successfully.

I tried to forcefully terminate the process, however, it returns 'process not found.'

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?  I'm experiencing the same issue but this time with the aspnetcore Kestrel server.  I can't bind another application to the port it was using until restarting (and no the process and no child process is running and nothing is actively listening on the port).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a windows machine then apps like apache usually are lanuched as a service.

You can close it with

> CMD+R -> services.msc , search for
>   apache and press stop

or

> cmd -> net stop apache

or

> cmd -> net stop apache2

Comment: Trying any of those three options are what causes the issue to occur.